# Returning json correctly to ajax from php

Tags: php, ajax, json

I have this snippet of code that is responding to an Ajax request. When it's parsed by jQuery.parseJSON, it fails to work correctly.

```
$fm_edit ->select_self($result['success']);
print_r(json_encode($fm_edit));
die();
```

I have run the output though http://jsonlint.com/ and the JSON is invalid because of the print_r adding `string(0) ""` to the front of the output. I've tried echoing the output as recommended else where, but that fails because json objects are not strings.

How do I correct this?

Comment: just use echo in php, and use `dataType: 'json'` on the ajax since you're expecting one. well in your case, its empty, so just handle it on the success block. sidenote: when you use  `dataType: 'json'`, you do not need to `jQuery.parseJSON` the response

Comment: As said by others, `echo` is commonly used. Does `var_dump()` work?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
echo json_encode($fm_edit)
```

Answer (score 0):

you're using `print_r` which would print the variable(Array) content. To make it more perfect for you `print_r` also returns the variable type. `echo` is the solution because it just prints the variable content.

Answer (score 0):

So this turned out to be an issue with a var dump for the same object type in an entirely unrelated part of the site.

Somehow it has been intercepting the AJAX request (I assume because it also handles $_POST data and because it hooks into the application earlier) and dumping out (for unrelated debug purposes) an object that was virtually identical aside from not entirely being valid json, which completely mislead me when that was returned to the JS layer instead of the expected response.

I'm going to add some conditions to disable that second process when an AJAX request is happening and that should resolve it.